# SQL Server 2008 T-SQL: How to implement increasing number space PER foreign key value (with thread safety)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This works but I feel there must be a better way.  I don't understand table/row locking very well.  I have a table and a SP to manage ever increasing transactions numbers (1,2,3, etc.) PER person:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonTransaction (
    PersonID int NOT NULL,
    TransactionID int NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO PersonTransaction VALUES (1,0), (2,0), (3,0)

CREATE PROCEDURE PersonNewTransaction
    @PersonID int
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE PersonTransaction
    SET TransactionID=TransactionID+1
    WHERE PersonID=@PersonID

    SELECT TransactionID
    FROM PersonTransaction
    WHERE PersonID=@PersonID
END

PersonNewTransaction 1
PersonNewTransaction 3
PersonNewTransaction 1

select * from PersonTransaction
PersonID TransactioID
1   2
2   0
3   1
```

Should I wrap the SP with a [transaction and sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) and call it a day or is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: You can use `OUTPUT` to atomically read the updated value (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177564.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comment from Alex

```
UPDATE PersonTransaction
   SET TransactionID=TransactionID+1 
output inserted.TransactionID
 WHERE PersonID=@PersonID
```

Comment: Since it's a single statement I'm guessing that wrapping it in a transaction adds NO value, right?

Comment: A single statement is in itself a transaction